# How to make keycloak sessions survive server restarts or upgrades?

Tags: session, keycloak, openid-connect, infinispan

Keycloak configuration and data is stored in a relational database, which is usally persisted to the hard disk. This includes data like realm settings, users, group- and role-memberships, auth flows and so on. But the user sessions will only be stored in an ephemeral in-memory infinispan cache. Therefore the session data in this cache is lost, when the keycloak server restarts.

There are many reasons why a restart of the Keycloak server is required. Major OS upgrades, Keycloak server upgrades to new versions, applying changes to keycloak e-mail templates or re-scheduling keycloak pods to other worker nodes in kubernetes or other cloud-based environments.

**How to persist the session data to survive restarts. Ideally without having to maintain a custom infinspan server or using keycloak "offline sessions".**

---

One solution could be to simply use so-called keycloak *"offline sessions"*, but these sessions also have huge disadvantages:

- they remain valid, even if the user logs out
- logging out users with the keycloak admin console is no longer possible

See: https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_admin/#_offline-access

---

*Will this problem still be present when keycloak > 17 is out and uses the all new quarkus distribution?* Because in the following articles claim goals like *Container-First Approach*, *Zero-Downtime Upgrade* and *Storage re-architecture*.

- https://www.keycloak.org/2021/10/keycloak-x-update
- https://www.keycloak.org/2020/12/first-keycloak-x-release.adoc

Comment: https://groups.google.com/g/keycloak-dev/c/sOBzG76f2FE

Answer (score 0):

As you already wrote in your question, using Infinispan would be the go-to solution. Infinispan can be used in two ways:

1. Infinispan running within Keycloak, which is the OOTB way of Keycloak --> Problem: when all Keycloak instances shut down, Infinispan is also down and sessions are lost
2. Infinispan running as an external cluster, with Keycloak connecting to this external cluster --> Problem: when all Infinispan nodes shut down (e.g. because of an incident or because of an update), then sessions are also lost

Only having Infinispan does not solve the session loss problem. But Infinispan caches can be backed by a database, e.g. a Postgres DB. Then sessions are stored in the ISPN cache and in a corresponding DB table. This can prevent session loss, both for the internal and the external Infinispan cluster.

So a solution to your problem could be to configure the internal ISPN caches to use a database persistence. This could look like this in your cache-ispn.xml:

```
<cache-container name="keycloak">
<!-- other config ... -->
     <replicated-cache name="sessions">
        <expiration/>
        <persistence>
            <string-keyed-jdbc-store xmlns="urn:infinispan:config:store:jdbc:14.0" dialect="POSTGRES">
                <connection-pool
                        connection-url="${env.ISPN_DATABASE_CONNECTION_URL}"
                        username="${env.ISPN_DATABASE_USERNAME:ispn}"
                        password="${env.INFINISPAN_DB_OWNER_PASSWORD:ispn}"
                        driver="org.postgresql.Driver"
                        properties-file="conf/ispn/infinispan-cache.properties"/>
                <string-keyed-table create-on-start="true" prefix="ispn">
                    <id-column name="id" type="VARCHAR(255)"/>
                    <data-column name="data" type="bytea"/>
                    <timestamp-column name="ts" type="BIGINT"/>
                    <segment-column name="seg" type="INT"/>
                </string-keyed-table>
            </string-keyed-jdbc-store>
        </persistence>
    </replicated-cache>
<!-- other config ... -->
</cache-container
```